# Conditional Logic applied to list of data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes containing farming revenue data. One is in the following format:

```
dataframe_1 <- read.table(
  text = "ID    2000   2001   2002   2003   2004
          Barley  180    143    434    232    656
          Wheat   764    667    667    554    121
          Oats    121    443    343    346    121",
  header = TRUE,
  check.names = FALSE
)
```

And a second empty dataframe, laid out in the format:

```
dataframe_2 <- read.table(
  text = "ID    2000   2001   2002   2003   2004
          Barley  NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
          Wheat   NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
          Oats    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA",
  header = TRUE,
  check.names = FALSE
)
```

The first data frame contains a huge amount of unnecessary information and I want to grab the data that is useful and summarize it in the second table.

I want to write a function that checks for matching column headers and row names and takes the corresponding value from the first table, and places it in the second.

Example: if column in both tables is named "2002" and rows are named "Wheat", replace the NA value in the second table with the value 667.

I have been attempting to use a nested for loop:

```
date_range <- c("2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004")

for (y in rownames(dataframe_2)) {
  for (x in date_range) {
    dataframe_1[[x]][y] <- dataframe_2[[x]][y]
  }
}
```

But simply receive unhelpful error messages that do not clarify the problem and the data frames are unchanged. One example being:

```
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, x, value = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,  : 
  replacement has 73 rows, data has 72
```

Comment: @Nate That's certainly a point of view. If you feel that way, I am perfectly fine with you pushing your edit again and I will not rollback. I think we should remove out comments as they are not answering the post; do you mind?

Comment: @joran I see your point about caution with `stringAsFactors` and here it is totally superfluous (so I removed it), thanks for the additional information.

Comment: I'm noticing a lot of discussion about subsequent arguments to the dataframes, revolving around check.names and stringsAsFactors. Neither of these have been used in the original code and could possibly be contributing to the problem?

Comment: Also read.table command was not used, rather these are excel tables that have imported with read.excel

Answer (score 1):

We can do this in base by a simple subset:

```r
df1[df1$ID %in% df2$ID, names(df2)]
```

Comment: This has not resulted in everything being QUITE right but it has definitely taken me a step closer. I suspect the underlying issue is now the tidyness of the argument data frames, thank you,

Comment: @user12042094 if you share output of the following commands, we can see your actual data structure and will be able to help you further: `dput(head(data1,3))` and `dput(head(data2, 3))`